# How to split or iterate through interleaved plain text and HTML inline markup using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, markup

I'm processing some 3rd party HTML which is semi-structured marked-up text (bold, italics, etc).

Here's a simplified sample of the structure:

```
<div>
  <strong class="term">one</strong>
  -
  <b class="defs">
    foo        
    <i class="pos">verb</i>
    bar
    <i class="pos">noun</i>
    baz
    <i class="pos">adjective</i>
    blah
  </b>
  <br>
  <strong class="term">two</strong>
  ... etc ...
</div>
```

In fact I've already processed it a bit to get it into this shape. I can handle the HTML elements OK, **but I haven't been able to figure out how to deal with the interleaved text and `<i>` elements.**

I'm happy with a solution that either splits the "defs" around the `<i>`s, a solution which iterates through the parts, etc. I would prefer not to mix jQuery and "raw" DOM API calls due to browser-specific quirks, but I understand if I can't avoid it. It seems from my shallow knowledge that jQuery doesn't have as good support for marked-up text as for "structural" HTML ...

Am I missing something obvious? This seems very hard to search for...

---

It turns out that in the real world data, the text runs and `<i>` nodes are always interleaved, but the first thing within the `defs` may be either one, and each text run can consist of one or more actual text nodes. This means that `<i>`s and text runs are not in matched pairs.

Good solutions might be to either add markup to each text run, or to iterate through, doing one thing for each `<i>` and another thing for each text run. I'm thinking `jQuery.contents()` with some node type checking must be the key...

Comment: What's your exact goal ? What's the problem ?

Comment: Either to parse the data, or convert into something easier to parse, by making it more semantic, or convert to JSON, etc. That could be something as similar as wrapping each `<i>` together with the text following it in some new element. I guess the difficulty is I can't find a way to "select" the text nodes like I can for the element nodes.

Comment: Check my updated answer to have idea on how you can do `nodeType` check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following to retrieve all the texts into an array

```
$(function(){
  var json = $('.defs').contents().map(function(){
     var text = $.trim($(this).text()); 
     return  text != "" ? text : null;
  });

  console.log(json);
});​
```

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/Z5AgL/

The above code Gives you a list of all the `defs` along with the textnode and `i`.

**Update**

Yeah you can do node type or name check using `this.nodeName` or `this.nodeType` inside the map function. `nodeType` for `textnode` is `3`. e.g. add this inside `.map()` and check

```
console.log(this.nodeName,this.nodeType);
```

So for this specific markup structure you can do the following to check if it's `<i>` or `textnode`

```
if(this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'i'){
    console.log('<i>');
    // do stuff for <i> here
}    
else{
    console.log('Text Node');            
    // it's text node
}  

// or with nodeType

if(this.nodeType == 3){
 // textNode
}else{
 // <i> 
}
```

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/Z5AgL/6/

Comment: Ha neat, ignores the semantic classes already in there but pretty much gets the same result anyway! It could be thrown off by when a text node contains one of the strings usually in an `i`, especially considering that the defs can start with either an `i` or a text node now that I've done some checking against more actual data.

Comment: Seems there's no silver bullet for getting this kind of thing done with jQuery alone, but your answers got me on the right path so you get the cookie (-:

Answer (score 1):

If your structure is always as you show us, you can do this :

```
var defs = [];
var def = null;
var tokens = $('.defs').text().split('\n');
for (var i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
    if (tokens[i].trim().length>0) {
        if (def==null) {
            def = {name:tokens[i]};
        } else {
            def.value = tokens[i];
            defs.push(def);
            def = null;
        }
    }
};
console.log(defs);
```

Of course, you'll have to add protections, or to enrich, depending on what you have but you get the spirit of the kind of manipulations you can do.

Another solution would have been to get all the parts in italic (with `$('.pos')`) and to look for their first position in `$('.defs').text()` (first position after the last extracted pair).

Comment: Ah interesting that this approach also ignores the semantic structure already present. It's also tripped up by the fact that the real world data can start with either an `i` or a text node now that I've looked at more of it more carefully. This suggests they can't really make key/value pairs so I should update the question.

Comment: My detailed solution is based on the fact that there are lines. If you want to use the `<i>`, you can do as I suggested after.

Comment: Ah with text matching? I didn't think of that. I was thinking of trying to get the next sibling node for each `<i>`, but now I'm leaning towards iterating through the `contents()` of each `.defs`. I guess there is no totally simple/straightforward way to do this kind of thing after all (-: